# Popular item purchases combination

Tags: sql

Looking to get a list of most popular combination of items purchased. Data table has the fields itemno and date. My code currently doesn't give me the output desired. In the table below the sales for A should be 8, and for A,B should be 6. Wanted to try use string_agg but that's not currently supported in the sql within databricks.

e.g.

[image]

Code

```
select itemcombo, count(itemcombo) as sales_ 
from (
  select trans, array_join(array_sort(collect_set(itemno)),',') as itemcombo
  from  a
  group by trans) b
group by itemcombo
```

Comment: If you want assistance, make it easy to help you. Provide code and sample data as properly formatted text. Images of code just can't be copied and edited.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Much better. But which dbms are you using?

Comment: whats the easiest way for me to find that out. Its sql in databricks